# SyntaxError: Missing ) in a Simple Scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have two divs with anchors inside (one with a class of 'renter', the other with a class of 'owner'). When clicked, the page should scroll to elements '#pageInclude119' and '#pageBContent120' respectively. However, I want them to go to a separate page if Javascript isn't work, so that's why they're linked. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="button renter"><a href="/for-residents-with-realty-services-property-management-company">i&rsquo;m a renter</a></div>

<div class="button owner"><a href="/for-owners-with-realty-services-property-management-company">I&rsquo;m an owner/investor</a></div>
```

and here's my Javascript (the preventDefault is to keep the link from going to another page, while the animate is supposed to scroll to an element in the same page):

```
$( document ).ready(
$('.renter a').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#pageInclude119").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

$('.owner a').on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#pageBContent120").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
);
```

For some reason, this script returns this error, and doesn't work:

"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few errors, missing function() {} and event parameter in the on click statements:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.renter a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#pageInclude119").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.owner a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#pageBContent120").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(
    // Code here
);
```

Use this

```
$(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Answer (score 0):

In the `$( document ).ready` you forgot to add a `function`:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax a bit wrong. The outermost block should be:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //.....
  //......
});
```

or you can use the shorthand:

```js
$(function() {
  //.....
  //......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the updated/working code.**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.renter a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#pageInclude119").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.owner a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#pageBContent120").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```